# How to enable inputs to write text in angular-ui-tree?

Tags: angularjs, tree

I use library [Angular UI Tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree)

In template where is going formatting tree I added input field for each node:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer.html">
  <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content">
    <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)">
      <span class="glyphicon"
            ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed}">
      </span>
    </a>
    $$node.title$$
    <input type="text" name="r" value="">
</div>
</script>
```

I can not edit this input, how to make this writtable?

Comment: Somebody knows?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to handle this as well. Looks like there is an open github issue for the project: https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree/issues/932

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is to add data-nodrag attribute to the node that contains the input.